# How should I understand a "for" statement in a tilemap?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-9-2d-arrays) online and I'm having troubles understanding the code which is written there.

```
public Tilemap() {
    int[][] tilemap = new int[30][50];

    System.out.println("New Tilemap created.");
    Random r = new Random();

    int rows = tilemap.length;
    int columns = tilemap[1].length;

    printTiles(rows, columns, tilemap, r);
}

public void printTiles(int rows, int columns, int[][] tilemap, Random r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            tilemap[i][j] = r.nextInt(5);
            System.out.print(" " + tilemap[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

I understand everything up until the `for` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            tilemap[i][j] = r.nextInt(5);
            System.out.print(" " + tilemap[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

The tutorial doesn't explain one bit about them. So if anyone could help me understand, what is the purpose of most of the lines in the `for` statement, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's iterating through the entire 2D array and placing random integers at every index.

I've commented the code below. Hopefully this explains it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //iterate through every row
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) { //iterate through every column
            tilemap[i][j] = r.nextInt(5); //place an integer between 0 (inclusive) and 5 (exclusive) at the specified location in the 2d array
            System.out.print(" " + tilemap[i][j]); //print the integer that was just placed with a preceding space
        }

        System.out.println(" "); //print a new line since we've reached the end of the row
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, and one more question. What does this line mean: `int columns = tilemap[1].length;`? That the columns are being generated from the `1` index?

Comment: @philosophicalintrovert It's a square array so you could put any index in there and get the same number. It's just an easy way to get the number of columns in the array. The columns are "generated" or more correctly "defined" by this line `int[][] tilemap = new int[30][50];` which is a 30 row 50 column array.